# huffman algorithm

Tags: c++, class, huffman-code

I'm making a program on the **HUFFMAN ALGORITHM** where I have one class of nodes (*hnode*) to contain the symbol (*name*) and its frequency of occurence (*freq*); and other class (*pq*) which is used to form the **tree** to get the code for the symbols. I have written only the relevant parts of the classes. Now when I try to run this program it always gets stuck in the while loop (*in main()*) when it enters *the while loop* second time. I've tried everything but still couldn't figure out why... Can somebody please help to make this code run !!

```
#define NPTR hnode*
class pq;
class hnode
{
    string name;
    int freq;
    friend class pq;

    public:

    NPTR phnode;
    void show () 
    { cout << "name = " << name << endl << ", freq= " << freq <<endl ; }

    hnode (string x, int fr): name(x), freq(fr)
    {
        phnode = this;
    }

    friend hnode operator + (hnode p, hnode q)
    {
        string s = q.name + p.name;
        int f = q.freq + p.freq ;
        hnode foo (s,f);
        return foo;
    }
};

class pq /// ascending priority queue
{
    struct node
    {
    NPTR data;
    node* next;
    node (NPTR p) : data(p), next(0) {}
    };
    public:
    int count;
    node* getnode (NPTR p) { return new node(p); }
    node* listptr;
    void place (NPTR );
    NPTR mindelete();
    pq() : listptr(0), count(0) {}
};

void pq::place (NPTR p)
{
    if(count == 0)
    {
        listptr = getnode(p);
    }

    else
    {
        node* foo = listptr, *bar = NULL;
        while( (foo!= NULL) && (p->freq >= foo->data->freq) )
        {
            bar = foo;
            foo = foo->next;
        }
        node* ptr = getnode(p);
        ptr->next = bar->next;
        bar->next = ptr;
    }
    ++count;
}

NPTR pq::mindelete()
{
    if(count==0) { cout<<"invalid\n"; exit(1);}
    NPTR val = listptr->data;
    listptr = listptr->next;
    --count;
    return val;
}

void main ()
{
    pq list;
    for ( int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        string s;
        int f;
        cin>>s>>f;
        NPTR p = new hnode(s,f);
        list.place(p);
    }
    while(list.count>1)
    {
        NPTR p1 = list.mindelete();
        NPTR p2 = list.mindelete();
        hnode po = (*p1)+(*p2); // overloaded operator
        NPTR p = &po;
        p->show();
        list.place(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Actually I didnt do it by myself, but I think the compiler does it for me.

Comment: I am not sure we have the same definition of debugger...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger

Comment: Your code above exits the loop just fine if you only have the lines with '.mindelete' and '.place' inside the loop.  This suggests some some missing logic.  If you don't understand what's wrong it's hard to determine what's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code's creating a locally scoped `hnode po` over here:

```
while(list.count > 1)
{
    NPTR p1 = list.mindelete();
    NPTR p2 = list.mindelete();
    hnode po = (*p1)+(*p2); // overloaded operator
    NPTR p = &po;
    p->show();
    list.place(p);
}
```

Then you're passing that around by address and you're making `pq::node` hold onto that. Sounds like a really bad idea since `hnode po` *goes out of scope* at the end of your while loop on every iteration.

In general, you want to be using smart points and RAII for automated memory management rather than new'ing and delete'ing all over the place.

Comment: Thanks Victor. This was exactly where it was stuck. I modified the + operator, created an object on heap there and returned a pointer to that object, storing it in NPTR p in while loop and now it runs all fine :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest having a look here:

[NIST adaptive Huffman](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/adaptiveHuffman.html)

and also here:

[NIST Huffman](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/huffmanCoding.html)

Code samples can be found there also.